# Do you understand mom/mother?

Tags: word-usage, phrases, kinship-terms

Why can we use '**dad**' and '**mom**' standalone, but should use a pronoun or an article with '**father**' and '**mother**'? For instance when brother and sister are speaking.

- Do you understand mom?
- Do you understand your mother?

'*Do you understand mother*' sounds like bad English.

The same works for other examples:

- Give dad this book.
- Give your father this book.

'*Give father this book*' sounds really bad.

Comment: Who are they? Kins? Siblings? Friends? Whose mom/dad? Unless you put 'your,' it can't be said whose mom/dad you are talking about. It has least to do with which word you are using!

Comment: This is a nuanced matter.  Don't trust your ear here. It's possible for a stranger or near stranger to ask "And how is mom doing?" when they wish to express *solicitude*.  It is often "bedside manner" for a nurse or doctor to speak this way, but it could be said by someone on a train platform with whom one has struck up a conversation.  And some families are more formal than others, and say "Father" and "Mother" instead of "Mom" and "Dad". *You'll have to ask Mother.* or *Mother, where's my blue hoodie?*

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo So, Father and Mother are formal but correct with no pronoun?

Comment: Grammatical as terms of address, certainly, though fairly rare in family contexts (usual when addressing people in religious orders). Grammatical as role-names within family, yes, but fairly rare compared to the informal "Mom" or "Ma" or  "Mum" and "Dad" or "Da' ".

Comment: I think the only difference is that you would likely use *your* in formal or heated situations. For example, if a mother is scolding her child, she might say "Wait until *your* father gets home!" Using dad vs. father, etc. has more to do with accepted usage in a family group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The words *dad/father and mom/mother* can be used without the pronouns *your, my, or our* only in conversations between the family members. In this case, they should be capitalized:

> Do you understand Mom?
>
> Do you understand Mother?
>
> Give Dad this book.
>
> Give Father this book.

Comment: Somehow Father and Mother sound really odd, whereas Dad and Mom sound okay.

Comment: Not odd at all, just more formal. You see the construction (give Mother/Father) all the time in British English, usually associated with upperclass people.

Answer (score 1):

The words mom/dad in your examples sound as bad as mother/father without "your" to me. I think you understand the words mom/dad as "my/your mother/father" in your perspective while the fact that all of these words (mom/dad/mother/father) are just nouns that should have a pronoun to make it more specific so that the others can understand which or whose mom/dad/father/mother you are talking about.